# The transmission distance of a signal

Tags: signal-detection, signal-power, radio, hardware, electrical-signal

I am no professional in this area so please forgive me if this question is too immature. And thanks in advance for any help and information.

I want to know how to calculate the transmission distance of a signal, say a radio wave or any type of signal that is used to transmit information (like transmitting sound, more specifically).

Theoretically an electromagnetic wave never "disappear," yet it will decay along the way of spreading hence the strength of the signal will be less and less, eventually becoming totally undetectable.

My question is, how far can a signal travel before it becomes undetectable? Is and how is this distance affected by factors like the working power of transmitter, medium of transmission (say, typically in air), environment (like in a city/countryside area), as well as other factors like the properties of the wave? (How) is this related to the receiver's ability?

To make the above more concrete (just to explain my question above, not to add more questions), I want to answer a question like this: what conditions are required (say how much power is needed for the sending device? What frequencies/wavelength? ...) if we want a send a signal from a device and the signal can be well received from, say 1 mile away in the city area (or a more open area like countryside)?

Comment: Look up "RF propagation models" and "link margin".

Comment: It's way complicated.  You have a couple of simple answers -- beyond that, the wavelength, the antennas, the terrain (i.e. rural vs. city, fields vs. forest), at some frequencies the weather -- all make a difference.  With the right choice of receiver, transmitter, and frequency, you can talk (via Morse code) around the world on one watt.  OTOH, an AM broadcast radio transmitter may need 50kW to get to the next county at the wrong time of day.  Search on "RF propagation", then the frequency you're interested in, then start reading.

Comment: Thanks very much for the all the comments and answers. I have accepted the first received answer now, while all the answers and comments are greatly helpful. But please keep commenting and posting answers with any related information and thought if you wish -- they'll all be immensely appreciated for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, you can always test your channel and adjust your power according to the channel state before sending any signal. Each channel is always unique regardless of being in a city or in more open area, so testing the channel is always ideal.

Generally, two crucial factors are affecting your transmission; path-loss and fading.

First, you want to know the path-loss function, which could be a priori defined as e.g.
$$
l(d) := (Ad)^{\alpha},
$$
where distance $d$ denotes the distance between the transmitter and a receiver. Path loss function depends on the frequency, characteristics of your antennas, and on the qualities of the channel (in [free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss) for isotropic antennas $A = \frac{4 \pi d f}{c}$ and $\alpha = 2$). Path-loss exponent $\alpha$ varies typically between $1.5$ (indoors) and $4$ (city).  This definition of $l$ works merely under certain specific conditions – particularly it is often applied when the receiver is in far-field. Other definitions could be $l(d) = (1 + Ad)^{\alpha}$, $l(d) = (A \max(d_0,d))^{\alpha}$ etc.

Second, you want to know how the strength of the received signal fluctuates. In the case of [line-of-sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation) (LOS), where there are no reflections, the signal strength in the receiver is constant. On contrary, in a city with a lot of obstacles, the received envelope $R$ is often considered to be [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_fading) distributed. When the channel is somewhere between LOS and Rayleigh, we have a [Rician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rician_fading) distributed envelope. The space-time scale in which the fluctuations takes place is called the coherence length, and it depends again on the frequency of your signal, receivers speed, etc. The fading effect is prevalent in microwave communications, but not that much with longer wavelengths.

To measure our channel quality, we define a signal-to-noise ratio for the power $R^2 := P$
$$
\text{SNR} = \frac{P/l(d)}{N},
$$
where $N$ is a mean noise power in the receiver. This is usually additive white Gaussian noise and it is caused by heat radiation, atmosphere, other transmitters etc.

If we are now about to send voice we need that the SNR is over some threshold $T$ (which depends on your device's abilities). That is, for a successful transmission, we want

$$
\frac{P/l(d)}{N} \geq T.
$$

Long story short, we need to know the path-loss function $l$, noise level $N$, and the threshold $T$ to determine the required transmitting power $P$ in the channel.

Notice that unless you have a LOS, the power $P$ will fluctuate around some mean if the receiver is moving and/or after some time (as the obstacles move). Sometimes the SNR will get higher than the threshold, but sometimes it will drop (deep fade). Of course, you could always increase the power so that the deep fading events get very unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

A really simple approach is to just use the [Friis transmission formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss):

$$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = D_t D_r \left( \frac{\lambda}{4\pi d} \right)^2$$

which leads to the [free space path loss formula (in dB)](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-fspl.aspx):

$$ FSPL = 20 \log_{10}(d) + 20\log_{10}(f) + 20 \log_{10} \left(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda}\right) -G_t - G_r$$

Then, it's up to the power of the transmitter and the sensitivity of the receiver. As MBaz says in a comment, that's where you'll get your link margin.